# document.close() function causes ie10 compatability mode to fail

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, mode

I'm using the following function openwin() to write a page and open it.
The problem is if I use myWindow.document.close(); it fails when using IE10 compatability mode.
Crash report says "The remote procedure call failed" referring to document.close().

If I step through with the debugger it does not fail (presumably it's closing the document automatically somewhere).

If I don't close the document (In any IE mode) the page waits for perhaps 30 seconds before loading the javascript (google translate). Presumably the page times out and self closes the document and then runs the javascript.

Any ideas what's causing this (failure in IE10 compatibility mode)?

Also - this problem ONLY occurs when the page contains scripts.

Thanks,

Fergal.

```
function openWin(){
    if( $('#worksheetbtn').data('created')==true){
        var day = new Date(); 
        var id = day.getTime();
        myWindow=window.open("",id);
        myWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
        myWindow.document.write('<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="8920959a5c7c1a2e-252a0ea397b87b27-g0d7aa06f124f9dec-14"></meta>');
        myWindow.document.write('<style type="text/css"> td {valign="top";} td.upper_line { border-top:solid 1px ;}table.fraction {border-top-color: #000000;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:0.5em; line-height: 2em; }</style> ');
        myWindow.document.write('<title> Steps To Maths Worksheet Creator - STM The software for Learning Maths Online. </title>');
        myWindow.document.write('</head>    <body>');
        myWindow.document.write('<div id="google_translate_element">Translate</div>');
        myWindow.document.write('<p>Steps To Maths </p>'    );
        myWindow.document.write($('#worksheetbtn').data('worksheet_html') );
        myWindow.document.write('</body>');
        myWindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript"> function googleTranslateElementInit() {  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: \'en\', autoDisplay: false}, \'google_translate_element\');}</script>');
        myWindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="\/\/translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>');


        myWindow.document.write('</html>');
        myWindow.focus();
//      myWindow.document.close(); 

    } else alert('The worksheet cannot be opened, please select a category, number of questions and click on the Load Questions button');
}
```

Comment: If you add a document.open() before the first write does it make a difference? [by default, the first document.write should call it internally, but you never know with IE]

Answer (score -1):

You can just use

```
myWindow.close();
```

Comment: `window.document.close` and `window.close()` are two different things